# Como colocar uma imagem de fundo no Jumbotron? Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Alguém poderia me ajudar a colocar uma imagem de fundo no jumbotron ?

Esse é o código:

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
   <div class="container">
       <h1 class="display-4">Biblioteca</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A melhor forma de fazê-lo é criando um novo arquivo para guardar as customizações de CSS, um "style.css" ou "custom.css" etc e definir os novos atributos para o "jumbotron":

```
.jumbotron-with-background {
    background-image: url(
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Daí é carregar este arquivo após o carregamento dos CSS do Bootstrap:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' href="/css/style.css">
```

E, finalmente, colocar tua customização no HTML...

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid jumbotron-with-background">
    ...
</div>
```

Isto vale para qualquer outra customização no Bootstrap, criando uma nova classe para complementá-lo ao invés redefinir classes já existentes.